# Setting containers within a loop

Tags: python

```
dictA = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
preA = {}
print hex(id(preA))
preB = {}
print hex(id(preB))
dicts = [preA, preB]         #<---- looks like I can't save it like this?

for d in dicts:
    print hex(id(d))
    d = dictA
print preA
print preB
```

OUTPUT:

```
0x13348b0
0x13357f0
0x13348b0
0x13357f0
{}
{}
```

Looks like it has same memory address but when I set `preA` or `preB` via the variable '`d`' and getting the value back from `preA` or `preB`, it's as if they were never set.

Can anyone explain whats going on here?

Comment: `d = dictA` rebinds `d`. `d` is just a reference, the `for` loop first pointed it to one dictionary, then to another. The list itself doesn't change because you didn't tell the list to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` is set to the current dictionary at the iteration of each loop. Setting `d = dictA` is pointless because `d` will change to the next dictionary as the first step.

Comment: my thinking was that d is the refence to preA so it translate to preA = dictA. What can i do so that d is basically preA?

Comment: You can only get `d` to transiently refer to preA, which is its initial state in when entering the body of the loop for the first time. Then it refers to dictA in your assignment `d = dictA`. To get preA = dictA, you will have to make an explicit reference statement.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that the thing you are assigning to is not actually the `dict` object, but the variable named `d`. If you `print hex(id(d))` after the assignment, you should see a different value. In order to actually change the `dict` value itself, you have to use some function on it that modifies it, e.g. `d["a"] = 1`, or more relevantly here `d.update(dictA)`.